# How do I strip a URL from a string and place it an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, url, loops

I'm working on building a small script that searches for the 5 most recent pictures tweeted by a service, isolates the URL and puts that URL into an array.

```
def grabTweets(linkArray) #brings in empty array
  tweets = Twitter.search("[pic] "+" url.com/r/", :rpp => 2, :result_type => "recent").map do |status|
  tweets = "#{status.text}" #class = string

  url_regexp = /http:\/\/\w/ #isolates link
  url = tweets.split.grep(url_regexp).to_s #chops off link, turns link to string from an array

  #add link to url array
  #print linkArray #prints []

  linkArray.push(url)
  print linkArray

  end
end

x = []
timelineTweets = grabTweets(x)
```

The function is returning things like this: ["[\"http://t.co/6789\"]"]["[\"http://t.co/12345\"]"]

I'm trying to get it to return ["http://t.co/6789", "http://t.co/1245"] but it's not managing that.

Any help here would be appreciated. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Why are you passing in an empty array that you populate? why not just call the method that returns the array and don't bother initializing and passing an empty array? timelineTweets = grabTweets()

Comment: Because I don't know what I'm doing :)

Comment: What would you suggest instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to grab URLs in Ruby is to use the [`URI::extract`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-extract) method. It's a pre-existing wheel that works:

```
require 'uri'
require 'open-uri'

body = open('http://www.example.com').read

urls = URI::extract(body)
puts urls
```

Which returns:

```
http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd
http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml
http://www.icann.org/
mailto:iana@iana.org?subject=General%20website%20feedback
```

Once you have the array you can filter for what you want, or you can give it a list of schemes to extract.

Answer (score 1):

[`grep`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) returns an array:

> **grep(pattern) → array**
>   **grep(pattern) {| obj | block } → array**
>
> Returns an array of every element in enum for which `Pattern === element`.

So your odd output is coming from the `to_s` call the follows your `grep`. You're probably looking for this:

```
linkArray += tweets.split.grep(url_regexp)
```

or if you only want the first URL:

```
url = tweets.split.grep(url_regexp).first
linkArray << url if(url)
```

You could also skip the `split.grep` and use [`scan`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-scan):

```
# \S+ should be good enough for this sort of thing.
linkArray += tweets.scan(%r{https?://\S+})
# or
url = tweets.scan(%r{https?://\S+}).first
linkArray << url if(url)
```

Answer (score 1):

To strip a url out a string and push into urls array, you can do:

```
urls = []
if mystring =~ /(http:\/\/[^\s]+)/
  urls << $1
end
```