# How do I convert URL array into string and then place it in blank array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, url, loops

I'm very new to Ruby and I'm trying to build a simple function that will search Twitter, grab a certain string with a URL, chop off that string and place the URL only into an empty array.

The end goal of the function is that it returns an array with 2 URLs inside that I can manipulate with another function.

I've been staring at this for a while and I'm completely unsure how to turn the arrays that URI::extract spits out into strings and then place them in an array.

Any help is much, much appreciated! Thank you!

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'twitter'
require 'json'
require 'uri'
require 'mechanize'

def grabTweets()
  urls = []

  tweets = Twitter.search("[pic] "+" path.com/p/", :rpp => 2, :result_type => "recent").map do |status|
  tweets = "#{status.text}" #class = string

  url = URI::extract(tweets) #class = array
  print url

  #turn each array into a string

  #place string in array

  #what do I return?

  end
end


timelineTweets = grabTweets()
```

Comment: It'd be much easier to help if you supplied the data given to `URI::extract` so we don't all have to install all the gems, since nothing is relevant except the output of `extract`. Also not sure what you're asking, since it *already* returns an array of strings.

Comment: The Twitter search done is "[pic] "+" path.com/p/". It's looking for the 2 most recent tweets with the beginning URL of path.com/p/

Comment: The data provided to `extract` is in the variable `tweets`. *How* that variable is initialized is irrelevant--what's important is what's in it.

Comment: My goal is for it to return [path.com/p/123, path.com/p/455]

Comment: @DaveNewton Right now it pulls this from twitter: At MissCollege [pic] — http://t.co/12345

Comment: I'm not getting through to you. Unless we install all the gems, we don't know (a) what data you're passing to `extract`, or (b) what `extract` is returning.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm sorry. I've provided the data stored in tweets above. 

When extract runs, it returs ["http://t.co/12345"]["http://t.co/67890"]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I strip a URL from a string and place it an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042715/how-do-i-strip-a-url-from-a-string-and-place-it-an-array)

Comment: 14 hours ago you created an almost identical question.

Comment: @theTinMan I did. But I didn't feel like I asked the question in the right way so I made another topic. Forgive me if that's not the right way to do things here.

Comment: If you feel you didn't ask the question the right way, you edit your question and add a note explaining why you changed it. That helps the people answering. Once that question is answered you move on and ask another new one. Asking the same question, or similar ones, repeatedly wastes our time.

Comment: @theTinMan Noted. Does that mean I need to ask more targeted questions that people can answer and interact accordingly?

Comment: @theTinMan Nevermind, figured it out. Thanks for your guidance and for not simply writing me off as a clueless noob. I appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URI::extract returns an array of URL Strings. You just have to put its output into your desired array.
You can do that the following way:

```
urls.concat(URI::extract(tweets))
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the

```
print url
```

(or add the line  `url`). Methods return the result of the last statement. `print` returns `nil`, so does your method grabTweets (more idiomatic: grab_tweets).